# is it possible to change sin6_scope_id for interface?

Tags: linux, network-programming

Using `if_nametoindex(3)` I can determine the `sin6_scope_id` for interface (f.e. eth0, eth1, etc).
Is it possible to change this value for interface using some API, tool or by editing some file?

I need this for testing reasons. But I do not have physical access to the device. Also it would be great to understand how this value is assigned.

Comment: You mean you want to e.g. swap the interface IDs for `eth0` and `eth1`?  What would be the point?

Comment: @JohnZwinck  yes. Exactly. I need this for testing reasons. But I do not have physical access to the device.